# if linux bootloader overwrites windows bootloader then how does it perform chainloading because there is no more a bootloader for windows now?

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

i cant undrestand if we install linux after windows and write grub bootloader over windows bootloader then how come it uses windows bootloader for chainloading because if windows bootloader is overwritten by grub in mbr

Answer (score 2):

Grub does not overwrite windows boot-loader instead it installs alongside windows loader. Grub and windows both need less space to be installed on so the extra space partition that is created during windows/Linux instillation is enough to keep both of them and still around 100MB space remains.

Answer (score 0):

Grub does not overwrite the Windows bootloader.
Actually, if you choose Windows on the GRUB menu, it starts the windows boot seaquence from its beggining, as far as I know.